# How do I execute multiple mysql queries in Jasper Reports (not what you think...)

Tags: jasper-reports, rank, infobright

I have a complex query that requires a rank in it.  I've learned that the standard way of doing that is by using the technique found on this page: http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/.  I'm using Infobright as the back end and it doesn't work quite as expected.  That is, while a standard MySQL engine would show the rank as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... Brighthouse (Infobright's engine) would return 1, 1, 1, 1, etc....  So I came up with a strategy of setting a variable, a function, and then execute it in the query.  Here's a proof of concept query that does just that:

```
SET @rank = 0;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS __GetRank;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION __GetRank() RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    SET @rank = @rank + 1;
    return @rank;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

select __GetRank() AS rank, id from accounts;
```

I then copied and pasted the function into Jasper Report's iReport and then compiled my report.  After executing it, I get syntax errors.  So I thought that perhaps the ; was throwing it off.  So at the top of the query, I put in DELIMITER ;.  This did not work either.

Is what I'm wanting to do even possible?  If so, how?  And if there's an Infobright way of getting a rank without writing a function, I'd be open to that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this.  I had my server side program execute a mysql script.  I then took the output and converted it to a CSV.  I then used this as the input data for my report.  A little convoluted, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Infobright does not support functions.
From the site: http://www.infobright.org/forums/viewthread/1871/#7485

> Indeed, IB supports stored procedures, but does not support stored functions nor user defined functions.

```
select if(@rank is null,@rank:= 0,@rank:= @rank +1) as rank, id from accounts
```

Does not work, because you cannot write to @vars in queries.

This:

```
 SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM mytable t1 
    WHERE t1.rankedcolumn > t2.rankedcolumn) AS rank, 
 t2.rankedcolumn
 FROM mytable t2 WHERE ...;
```

will work, but is very slow of course.

**Disclaimer**, not my code, but Jakub Wroblewski's (Infobright founder)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.  That works great MySQL, but not using the brighthouse (Infobright) engine.  It would display rank as 1 for all elements in brighthouse.

Comment: Have you tested it?, because then the output should be all 0's not 1's.

Comment: Alternatively you can write a stored procedure that writes to a temp table and then read the temp table.

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect infobright specific stuff, why is there **no** tag for infobright?

Comment: I tried tagging it infobright, however; it said I had to have 1500 reputation points before creating my own tag.  Strange that it's never been created before.

Comment: I requested a tag "infobright", got it a few minutes later :-) until the tag was moderated and removed :-(.

Comment: I'd definitly suggest putting infobright in the title though, maybe the moderator will wake up and allow the tag to be added.

Comment: Infobright apparently does allow for functions.  I finally figured out a solution.  See below if you're curious.